# end of daylight savings time

Tags: python, timezone, python-datetime, dst, timedelta

I'm trying to verify if my understanding about pythons time (and daylight savings time) handling is correct. I've written the following code:

```py
import datetime
import zoneinfo

def test_switchover() -> None:
    zone = zoneinfo.ZoneInfo('Europe/Berlin')
    
    expected = datetime.datetime(year=2022, month=10, day=30, hour=2, minute=30, fold=1, tzinfo=zone)

    base = datetime.datetime(year=2022, month=10, day=30, hour=2, minute=30, fold=0, tzinfo=zone)
    got = base + datetime.timedelta(hours=1)

    assert expected == got
```

(note that `expected` has fold=1, which marks it as the second occurrence of 2:30)

Daylight savings time in Germany ends on 2022-10-30. Clocks are moved back from 03:00:00 CEST to 02:00:00 CET.

All datetime objects in my code are timezone aware. Therefore, 1 hour after 02:30:00 should again be 02:30:00. But the assertion fails!

```
>       assert expected == got
E       AssertionError: assert datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 30, 2, 30, fold=1, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='Europe/Berlin')) == datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 30, 3, 30, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='Europe/Berlin'))

tests/test_python_dst_switchover.py:12: AssertionError
```

Why?

(python 3.10)

Comment: Because `timedelta()` is dumb and doesn't care about DST in current timezone. I highly recommend you to perform all datetime calculations in UTC and set timezone only for output.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with `timedelta`. It represents an *interval*, regardless of when that interval *starts*. It's `datetime` that creates a new instance  given one instance and an interval. The problem is that `expected` uses the exact same timezone as `base`; nothing indicates whether it should be the "second" occurrence of 2:30am.

Comment: @chepner `expected` has fold=1, which indicates that it's the second occurrence of 2:30

Comment: Missed that. I stand by assertion that `timedelta` is not responsible for this, though. :)

Comment: @OlvinRoght I think your first statement is simply wrong. And second, [UTC is no silver bullet either](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2019/03/27/storing-utc-is-not-a-silver-bullet/).

Comment: @FObersteiner, there are always exceptions, that's why developers haven't been replaced by scripts yet :) My statement comes from years of experience managing various projects, this DST problem happened dozens of times and UTC is a common way to avoid it.

Comment: @FObersteiner, some misunderstanding happened. I haven't meant that implementation of `timedelta` is somehow bad, it's just as simple as it should be, I've tried to say that you should not expect too much from it.

Answer (score -2):

I think the change operates at midnight, isn't it so?

De facto in France it changes at midnight I think and I think in most Europe it should be the same thus Python may consider this to be the case across Europe.

Comment: Nope. See https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/sozv/SoZV.pdf (relevant German law, in German) or https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/DE/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A32000L0084 (relevant EU directive)

Comment: De facto in France it changes at midnight I think and I think in most Europe it should be the same thus Python may consider this to be the case across Europe.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_France: "Metropolitan France follows the summer time schedule in Europe. Summer time starts on the last Sunday in March at 01:00 UTC, when local time changes from 02:00 (UTC+01:00) to 03:00 (UTC+02:00), and ends on the last Sunday in October at 01:00 UTC, when local time changes from 03:00 (UTC+02:00) to 02:00 (UTC+01:00)"